# How to pass a polyline path from C++ to QML using Q_PROPERTY()

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to pass a path from C++ to QML by using `Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList path READ path)`, but it shows an error message `QML MapPolyline: Unsupported path type`.

When I googled what kind of data type is appropriate for passing a path from C++ to QML, the results said that I can (maybe only) use QVariantList, QVariant::fromValue() and QGeoCoordinate. So, according to this, my code is like:

#### In cpp(summary)

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList path READ path NOTIFY pathChanged)
QVariantList path() {
    return m_path;
}

signals:
    void pathChanged();

void DroneModel::addMarker(QObject *marker, double latitude, double longitude) {
    drone->addMarker(marker, latitude, longitude);
    QGeoCoordinate *coord = new QGeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude, 0);
    if (coord->isValid()) {
        m_path.append(QVariant::fromValue(coord));
    }

    emit pathChanged();
}
```

#### and in QML

```
Map {
    id: map
    ...
    MapPolyline {
        id: dronePath
        line.color: 'green'
        line.width: 3
        path: droneModel.path
        /* in main.cpp, 
         * engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("droneModel", &droneModel);
         */
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var targetLocation = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y);
            map.addMarker(targetLocation);
        }
    }

    function addMarker(targetLocation) {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/marker.qml");
        var marker = component.createObject();
        var targetCoordinate = map.toCoordinate(targetLocation);

        droneModel.addMarker(marker, targetCoordinate.latitude, targetCoordinate.longitude);
    }
}
```

Actually, I found a way to make polyline with C++ and QML, but it didn't use Q_PROPERTY() and `path: droneModel.path`.

Is there a way using Q_PROPERTY()? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? A see you do use property.

Comment: What is the type of `m_path`?

Comment: @folibis my code is getting an error QML MapPolyline: Unsupported path type.

Comment: @m7913d m_path is QVariantList.

Comment: Ok, it looks that `MapPolyline.path` requires [geopath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-geopath.html), not `list<coordinate>`. Perhaps some bug or documentation leaks. As an indirect confirmation of this look at [setPath(geopath path)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mappolyline.html#setPath-method). I guess you have to return `QGeoPath` from C++ instead of `QVariantList`. Btw I still can't understand why you pass point to C++ instead of manipulate it in QML.

Comment: @folibis Sorry for a late response. You mean that `Q_PROPERTY(QGeoPath path READ path NOTIFY pathChanged)`, `QGeoPath path() {}`? If so, it's still not working. And I think it seems the same as `QVariantList` because `QGeoPath.path` is `QVariantList`.

Comment: @folibis I'm a newbie of Qt, and my superior told me each drone will have a path so it should be managed on C++.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

In cpp,

```
if (coord->isValid()) {
    m_path.append(QVariant::fromValue(*coord));
}
```

is working instead of

```
if (coord->isValid()) {
    m_path.append(QVariant::fromValue(coord));
}
```